# How do I prevent Kubuntu from forgetting its sticky keys settings?

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04 and very often it forgets its settings that  sticky keys are turned on by default?

In Accessibility → Sticky Keys, Use Sticky Keys and lock Sticky Keys are marked. At least that is my poor english translation from German on how these labels must be called.

Often when I boot into my system, the sticky keys do not work. Then I have to start system settings and to mark these options off and on again and commit.

Also when I log into Kubuntu in lightdm greeter sticky keys do not work. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem: sometimes KDE does not have Sticky Keys set on boot. This script turns on sticky keys:

```
#!/bin/bash

xkbset exp 120 =b =r -m =ma =a -st =twokey =latchlock -sl -bo =f =dumbbell -led =feature =slowwarn =slowpress =slowaccept =slowreject =slowrelease =bouncereject =stickybeep =ov1 =ov2 =ignoregrouplock
xkbset b r rate 660 40 perkeyrepeat 00ffffffdffffbbffadfffefffedffff9ffffffffffffffffff7ffffffffffff -m 1 ma 160 40 30 30 500 -a st -twokey -latchlock -sl 500 -bo 500 f dumbbell -led feature slowwarn slowpress slowaccept -slowreject -slowrelease bouncereject -stickybeep -ov1 -ov2 groupswrap wrap 1 ignoregrouplock nullify -shift -lock -control -mod1 -mod2 -mod3 -mod4 -mod5 ignorelock -shift -lock -control -mod1 -mod2 -mod3 -mod4 -mod5
```

You can put the script in i.e. `~/bin/stickykeys.sh`, give it executable permissions with `chmod +x ~/bin/stickykeys.sh`, and then add a line to run it to your `~/.profile` script:

```
~/bin/stickykeys.sh
```